# concurrent.futures multithreading with 2 lists as variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrent.futures

So I would like to multi-thread the following working piece of code with concurrent futures but nothing I've tried so far seems to work.

```
def download(song_filename_list, song_link_list):

    with requests.Session() as s:
    
        login_request = s.post(login_url, data= payload, headers= headers)

        for x in range(len(song_filename_list)):

            download_request = s.get(song_link_list[x], headers= download_headers, stream=True)

            if download_request.status_code == 200:
                print(f"Downloading {x+1} out of {len(song_filename_list)}!\n")
                pass
            else:
                print(f"\nStatus Code: {download_request.status_code}!\n")
                sys.exit()

            
            with open (song_filename_list[x], "wb") as file:
                file.write(download_request.content)
```

The 2 main variables are the `song_filename_list` and the  `song_link_list`.

The first list has names of each file and the second has all their respective download links.
So the name and link of each file are located at the same position. 
For example: `name_of_file1 = song_filename_list[0]` and `link_of_file1 = song_link_list[0]`

---

This is the most recent attempt at multi-threading:

```
def download(song_filename_list, song_link_list):

    with requests.Session() as s:
    
        login_request = s.post(login_url, data= payload, headers= headers)

        x = []
        for i in range(len(song_filename_list)):
            x.append(i)


        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.submit(get_file, x)


def get_file(x):
    
    download_request = s.get(song_link_list[x], headers= download_headers, stream=True)

    if download_request.status_code == 200:
        print(f"Downloading {x+1} out of {len(song_filename_list)}!\n")
        pass
    else:
        print(f"\nStatus Code: {download_request.status_code}!\n")
        sys.exit()

        
    with open (song_filename_list[x], "wb") as file:
        file.write(download_request.content)
```

Could someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?
Cause nothing happens after the `get_file` function call.
It skips all the code and exits without any errors, so where is my logic wrong?

---

EDIT 1:

After adding prints to:

```
print(song_filename_list, song_link_list)
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            print("Before executor.map")
            executor.map(get_file, zip(song_filename_list, song_link_list))
            print("After executor.map")
            print(song_filename_list, song_link_list)
```

And to the start and end `get_file` and its `file.write`.

The output is as follows:

```
Succesfully logged in!

["songs names"] ["songs links"]    <- These are correct.
Before executor.map
After executor.map
["songs names"] ["songs links"]    <- These are correct.

Exiting.
```

In other words values are correct but it skips the `get_file` in the `executor.map`.

---

EDIT 2:

Here are the values used.

- `song_filename_list = ['100049 Himeringo - Yotsuya-san ni Yoroshiku.osz', '1001507 ZUTOMAYO - Kan Saete Kuyashiiwa.osz']`
- `song_link_list = ['https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/100049/download', 'https://osu.ppy.sh/beatmapsets/1001507/download']`

---

EDIT 3:

After some tinkering around it would seem that this works.

```
for i in range(len(song_filename_list)):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.submit(get_file, song_filename_list, song_link_list, i, s)
```

```
def get_file(song_filename_list, song_link_list, i, s):
    
    download_request = s.get(song_link_list[i], headers= download_headers, stream=True)

    if download_request.status_code == 200:
        print("Downloading...")
        pass
    else:
        print(f"\nStatus Code: {download_request.status_code}!\n")
        sys.exit()
    
    with open (song_filename_list[i], "wb") as file:
        file.write(download_request.content)
```

Comment: The function you are trying to make concurrent writes to the disk, have you verified that it indeed wrote the files?

Comment: As you are trying to parallelize only one function over multiple inputs stored in an iterable you could use the executor `.map()` method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `download()` function you submit the whole array while you should submit each items:

```py
def download(song_filename_list, song_link_list):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        login_request = s.post(login_url, 
            data=payload, 
            headers=headers)

        for i in range(len(song_filename_list)):
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                executor.submit(get_file, i)
```

You can simplify this with the executor `.map()` method:

```py
def download(song_filename_list, song_link_list):
  with requests.Session() as session:
    session.post(login_url, 
        data=payload, 
        headers=headers)

  with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(get_file, song_filename_list, song_link_list)
```

Where the `get_file` function is:

```py
def get_file(song_name, song_link):
  with requests.Session() as session:
    download_request = session.get(song_link, 
        headers=download_headers, 
        stream=True)

  if download_request.status_code == 200:
    print(f"Downloaded {song_name}")
  else:
    print(f"\nStatus Code: {download_request.status_code}!\n")
  
  with open(song_name, "wb") as file:
    file.write(download_request.content)
```

This avoid sharing state between threads, which avoids potential data races.

If you need to monitor how much songs have been downloaded, you can use [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io) which has a `thread_map` iterator wrapper that does exactly this.

Comment: So I tried both the examples you provided and none work. 
And to answer your question above, all the concurrency methods I tried,
(the 2 you provided, and the others I wrote myself) do not write anything to the disk.

Comment: The concurrent code should be right, can you add debug prints everywhere to see where is the issue (when submitting work, beginning of get_file, in file writing, etc...)? Also, remove `sys.exit()` to see more errors.

Comment: Edited my question with the outputs and also removed the `sys.exit()`.

Comment: Thank you, can you add print in the get_file (before/after the get requests, in the with open(…), etc.).

Comment: All of them have prints as well, i guess i didn't make it clear in the edit. Nothing prints from inside the `get_file()`. Seems like it's not even called by the `executor.map()`.

Comment: Definitely weird, could you send me some samples of song_link and song_name list to try to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I know right? I edited my answer again providing the values you asked.

Comment: Also the `song_list` is never used in your `get_file(song_name, song_list)` but I am guessing you meant `song_link`. In any case that doesn't make any difference either.

Comment: Yes this is `song_link` and there was an unneeded `zip` in the `map`, I removed it and it worked on my computer. I updated the answer.

Comment: I am getting a 401 error cause it needs authentication when I am using your `requests.Session()`.                                                                        Edit:  When I try to use my open `s` session, the `get_file` is called but no requests or writes are made. I cannot pass the open session cause it's not iterable. Also thanks for barring with me and my noobliness.

Comment: You should do the request inside the `with requests.Session()`. I updated my answer, if this does not work you may have to pass the session to the `get_file` method.

Comment: Ah, thats so obvious. Im kinda mad that I didn't think of that myself. I'll try it when I get home and I'll infrom you about the results.

Comment: Well I was tinkering around and found something (see edit 3), but I didn't get to try your suggestion cause I am getting a 429 and it needs about an hour to cooldown. I will try it tomorrow though and see what works best after I do some timing. Thank you very much.